# How to get parent frame from page level?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, parent

I have a window with a frame and few pages. When the window is loaded the frame is navigating to welcome page and when I click a button inside welcome page I want parent frame to navigate to another page. To do that I need to access parent frame from page level but I can't figure out how to do this. I tried code below but it's returning null:

```
private void myButton_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  SecondPage secPage = new SecondPage();
  ((this.Parent) as Frame).Navigate(secPage);
}
```

I checked what `this.parent` is returning and it is null.
How can I get parent frame so I can navigate from one page to another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Page also has a property called `NavigationService`. You can use this property for convenience to navigate between pages:

```
private void myButton_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  SecondPage secPage = new SecondPage();
  NavigationService.Navigate(secPage);
}
```

To access the parent Frame, you have to use `VisualTreeHelper` to walk up, and find the Frame. You can search more about it. Anyway using the `NavigationService` property is better.

Comment: Yep. That's the thing i was looking for. Marked as answer. Thank You for your help.

Comment: That looks awful to mess with, I'm going with the "good old" "creating a static field somewhere gimmick"